# How to attach image in doc file using CakePhp?

Tags: php, cakephp, doc

Here, I want to add a image a doc file header. I'm using Cakephp 2. Help me to add a image in header of doc file.
When I try to add it is showing some problem. I try to use from my directory of cakephp and I also try to using image link.

```
public function admin_get_member_detail() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $data = $this->request->data;
            $this->loadModel('Organization');
            $this->loadModel('VoteResult');
            $this->loadModel('VoteReResult');
            $orgData = $this->Organization->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Organization.member_id' => $data['Designation']['member_id'])));

            //$image = $this->Html->image('ica-logo.png', array('style' => 'height:100px;width:500px;border: thin solid black; border-radius:5px;'));


            $VoteResult = $this->VoteResult->query('select vote.election_id,vote.candidate_id,vote.election_phase,candidate.name,candidate.id,candidate.designation,designation.id,designation.name,sum(vote.vote_val) as total from tbl_vote_result as vote  join tbl_candidate as candidate on candidate.id = vote.candidate_id join tbl_designation as designation on designation.id = candidate.designation
            where organization_id =' . $orgData['Organization']['id'] . ' group by vote.candidate_id ORDER BY total DESC ');
            $ReVoteResult = $this->VoteReResult->query('select vote.election_id,vote.candidate_id,vote.organization_id,vote.election_phase,vote.candidate_deg,candidate.name,candidate.id,candidate.Organization,designation.id,designation.name,sum(vote.vote_val) as total1 from tbl_re_vote_result as vote  join tbl_candidate as candidate on candidate.id = vote.candidate_id join tbl_designation as designation on designation.id = vote.candidate_deg
            where vote.organization_id = ' . $orgData['Organization']['id'] . ' group by vote.candidate_id ORDER BY total1 DESC');
            //pr($ReVoteResult);die;
            if (!empty($VoteResult)) {
                header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=" . $orgData['Organization']['name'] . '_' . date("H:i:s") . '.doc');
                $now_date = date('d-m-Y H:i');
                echo "<html>";
                echo "<head>";
                //echo ".<?= $this->Html->image('ica-logo.png', array('style' => 'height:100px;width:500px;border: thin solid black; border-radius:5px;')); 

                echo "<img src='https://en.facebookbrand.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/facebook-live-brc-preview2.png'/>\n";

                echo "</head>";
                echo "<body>";
                echo "<div style='font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;'>" . $orgData['Organization']['name'] . "</div>\n";
                echo "<div>Date:$now_date</div>";
                echo "<br>";
                echo "<br>";
                echo "<table align='center' style='text-align:center' border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>";
                echo "<tr><td colspan='3'>For Board Member</td></tr>";
                echo"<tr><th>Sl No.</th><th>Candidate Name</th><th>Total Vote</th></tr>";
                foreach ($VoteResult as $key => $res) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . ++$key . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $res['candidate']['name'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $res[0]['total'] . "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
                echo "</table>";
                echo "<br>";
                echo "<table align='center' style='text-align:center' border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>";
                echo "<tr><td colspan='3'>For President</td></tr>";
                echo"<tr><th>Sl No.</th><th>Candidate Name</th><th>Total Vote</th></tr>";

                echo "</table>";
                echo "</body>";
                echo "</html>";
                die;
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Member Id Invalid'));
                $this->redirect($this->referer());
            }
        }
    }
```